# MS SQL dead lock for multi thread

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a very simple table SEQ_NO in MS SQL server 2014, the table structure is as following:

```
 CREATE TABLE SEQ_NO(
        KEY_CODE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        CURR_SEQ_NO numeric(38, 0) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (KEY_CODE)
        )
```

This table has only 4 records, each of them contains a sequence number. I have a program which has many threads access this table with hibernate to increase the sequence number by 1 and retrieve the increased sequence number.

For example, thread 1-10 increases and retrieves the sequence number from key_code_1 and thread 11-20 increases and retrieves the sequence number from key_code_2 etc.

I handled the exception for the threads accessing the same record but not handling the exception for the threads accessing different records since the table is row-locked. (i.e. the exception in-between thread 1-10 is properly handled, but exceptions between thread 1 and thread 11 is not handled).

It works fine with oracle 10g and hibernate3. Recently, the database is upgraded to SQL server 2014 and hibernate is upgrade to version4 and the program does not work! Sometimes thread 1 and thread 11 will go to deadlock even they are accessing the different row of the table! I am not sure why this happens and how can resolve this problem.

I have used the following script to check the table is row locked:

```
Query1 to lock one row:
begin tran T1;
update SEQ_NO set CURR_SEQ_NO = CURR_SEQ_NO+1 where KEY_CODE = 'KEY_CODE_1';
select CURR_SEQ_NO from SEQ_NO where KEY_CODE = 'KEY_CODE_1';

Query2 to check another row:
update SEQ_NO set CURR_SEQ_NO = CURR_SEQ_NO+1 where KEY_CODE = 'KEY_CODE_2';
select CURR_SEQ_NO from SEQ_NO where KEY_CODE = 'KEY_CODE_2';
```

I am able to get the sequence number for the 2nd query.

Comment: Hi, deadlock events are usually logged by SQL Server. You can see it using MS SQL Management Studio. Every event contains detail informations about deadlock - sql queries, victims, locked resources, etc. and you can also visualize it graphically. Go to Management =>Extended Events=>Sessions=>system_health=>package0.eventfile and then look for events with the name 'xml_deadlock_report'. Could you post us XML data of some deadlock (move your cursor over the xml value and do double-click to open complete xml data in a new tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by disable the lock escalation and turn off the page locks:

```
ALTER TABLE SEQ_NO SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE);
ALTER INDEX SEQ_NO_PK ON SEQ_NO; SET (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
```